# programmatically navigate a linq to sql result

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have the following....

```
var jobsApplications = ( from applications in db.applications
                        where applications.employeeId == LogedUser.Id
 select new { applications.id, applications.jobId, applications.confirmationDate });
```

Now I want to navigate this result like

```
foreach "something" in jobsApplications
```

But I don't now what to put in something since the select new create a new class.

Any suggestions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you can let the compiler do the work for you:

```
foreach (var application in jobApplications)
{
    // use the application wisely
}
```

Comment: This is in fact one of the reasons they created var.  For referencing anonymous types in a type-safe way.

Comment: yes. var is the only way to do this as you are projecting out an anonymous type.

Comment: What an intelligent compiler..
And of course Programmer
Thanks Mr. Fredrik

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `Array.ForEach()` to iterate through your `IEnumerable` or `List`. This is a bit more heavyweight.

```
 Array.ForEach(jobsApplication, jobApp => {

    if (jobApp.City == "Chicago")
    {
      jobApp.Approved = true;
    }
});
```

If you want a simple foreach, then you can type the anonymous class as `var`

```
foreach (var jobApp in jobApplications)
{
     if (jobApp.City == "Chicago")
    {
      jobApp.Approved = true;
    }
}
```